# Add new dynamic attribute with nil value

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having problems adding a new dynamic attribute to mongoid document with a value of `nil`

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
end
```

```rb
u = User.find(id)
u.write_attribute(:bar, nil)
puts u.bar
# => nil
u.save!

u = User.find(id)
puts u.bar
# => NoMethodError (undefined method `bar for #<User:0x00007fe87a97cfd8>)
```

Adding a new attribute with any other value than `nil` works fine.

```rb
u = User.find(id)
u.write_attribute(:foo, "a")
puts u.foo
# => "a"
u.save!

u = User.find(id)
puts u.foo
# => "a"
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use #set to set attribute values to nil. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#atomic.

```
irb(main):024:0> u.set(foo: nil)
D, [2020-10-05T21:31:20.167950 #18418] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:14400 req:15 conn:1:1 sconn:1088 | mongoid.update | STARTED | {"update"=>"users", "ordered"=>true, "updates"=>[{"q"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f7bc8642c97a647f27735c6')}, "u"=>{"$set"=>{"foo"=>nil}}}], "$db"=>"mongoid", "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x7620 type=uuid data=0x606db89de7a04adf...>}}
D, [2020-10-05T21:31:20.169268 #18418] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:14400 req:15 | mongoid.update | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
=> #<User _id: 5f7bc8642c97a647f27735c6, created_at: 2020-10-06 01:29:08.638566093 UTC, updated_at: 2020-10-06 01:29:20.656350934 UTC, bar: nil, bar1: 1, foo: nil>
```

Then #attributes works as expected:

```
irb(main):023:0> User.find(u.id).attributes
D, [2020-10-05T21:30:18.758322 #18418] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:14400 req:14 conn:1:1 sconn:1088 | mongoid.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f7bc8642c97a647f27735c6'), "$and"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f7bc8642c97a647f27735c6')}]}, "$db"=>"mongoid", "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x7620 type=uuid data=0x606db89de7a04adf...>}}
D, [2020-10-05T21:30:18.759791 #18418] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:14400 req:14 | mongoid.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f7bc8642c97a647f27735c6'), "updated_at"=>2020-10-06 01:29:20.656 UTC, "created_at"=>2020-10-06 01:29:08.638 UTC, "bar1"=>1, "foo"=>nil}
```

If you believe write_attribute should persist attributes with nil values, you can create a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID describing your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in the docs for [Mongo::Attributes::Dynamic](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields):

> If the attribute does not already exist on the document, Mongoid will not provide you with the getters and setters and will enforce normal method_missing behavior. In this case you must use the other provided accessor methods: ([] and []=) or (read_attribute and write_attribute).

So you can just use `user[:bar]` or `user.read_attribute(:bar)`

Comment: I am aware of that, but In my example I'm using ```write_attribute``` to set a new attribute and I expect it to be accessible after saving, which is not true when I set the attribute to nil.

Comment: I don't know Mongo too well, are you sure it behaves as though a key with a nil value _exists_? What happens when you look it up in Mongo directly? How does this compare to the behavior when you look up a key that wss never set at all?